# Why my JavaScript isn’t working with my html 5?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files, the first file name `Web.htm`
and the second file name Web.js

**Web.htm**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Web.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.js**

```
alert('Hello, World');
```

I already put the two files in the same folder but when I run the `Web.htm`, there isn’t have any box that show up and say `Hello, World`

But when remove the `src` in the `<script>` in the html file like this

```
<script>
    alert('Hello, World');
</script>
```

It still working, so what happened with my JavaScript, did I need to host a website to make it work? I’m actually isn’t host it yet.

Sorry if this question is stupid, I’m actually a beginners of JavaScript.

Edit: I fix the scr to src but it still isn’t work.

Edit: I fix the problem, I installed and configure the HTTP server like esqew said in the comment and it work. Look like my computer isn’t installed the HTTP server yet, sorry you guy.

Comment: You misspelled src

Comment: How are you serving these files? What server are you using?

Comment: It still isn’t work!

Comment: I actually didn’t host the website yet

Comment: I'm not talking about hosting the site; I'm asking what kind of server are you using to serve these files *locally*? Apache? nginx? If you *aren't* using a server and are simply pointing your browser to the local file (usually via the `file:///` URI schema) cross-referencing files like this will be disallowed for security. Install and configure a proper HTTP server and this should work.

Comment: Oh, it working, thank @espew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo.

try:
`<script src="Web.js"></script>`

When you are using a JavaScript file, you should NOT use HTML tags:

change your web.js file from:

```
<script>
    alert('Hello, World');
</script>
```

to

```
alert('Hello, World');
```

Comment: It still isn’t work, look at my edit.

Comment: Please flag or vote to close instead of answering questions that are obviously typos.

Comment: But did you know how to fix this? I post this on my phone and my computer use an IDE, I already checked my computer for typo but there is no problem with typo, the problem with typo is I post it in my phone.

Comment: - @Higg2020 Please check the edited answer to fix your web.js file

Comment: <script>
    alert('Hello, World');
</script> This is when I fix the script in my html file to this and it working, but I fix the problem by installed the HTTP server, tks you anyway.